# Looping issue in Tinybutstrong

Tags: tinybutstrong

I've the data structures as shown below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => dummy0
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [project_names] => project0
                    [dates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5
                            [1] => 11
                            [2] => 28
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => dummy1
            [projects] => Array
                (
                    [project_names] => project1
                    [dates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 10
                            [1] => 12
                            [2] => 28
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'ld like to get the output as following format

> dummy0
>
> ```
>    Project0  
>     5
>     11
>     28
> ```
>
> dummy1
>
> ```
>   Project1
>    10
>    12
>    28
> ```

I've used below snippet but didnt get the oupput as I excepted

```
                  [replies;block=begin;sub1=projects]

                      [replies_sub1.val;block=tr;sub1=dates]
                        [replies_sub1_sub1.val;block=td]

                  [replies;block=end;comm=text:p]
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your sub-data `dates` is actually under 2 levels of columns: projects/dates. And TBS does not support such data structure for the automatic sub-block.

The solution is to change your data structure in order to have it like this :

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => dummy0
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 11
                    [2] => 28
                )
            ....
        )
    ....
```

If you cannot change the structure, you can simply use parameter `ondata` with a custom function that will create a new (virtual) column in your data.

PHP:

```
function f_ondata($BlockName,&$CurrRec,$RecNum) {
    $CurrRec['dates_z'] = $CurrRec['projects']['dates'];
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="border: solid 1px red;">

    [replies;block=begin;sub1=dates_z;ondata=f_ondata]

    <table border="1">

      <tr>                
        <td>
            [replies.projects.project_names]
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>                
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            [replies_sub1.val;block=tr]
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>

    <text:p> [replies;block=end;comm=text:p] </text:p>
<div>
```